# how to remove hover on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm working on a jQuery game. I have a 4 `div`s in a 2x2 design. The player needs to pick 1 option and verify with another button. The thing is, I have a hover effect adding a class which changes the background with a low opacity, and a click effect setting the background with a higher opacity. For `div`s 2, 3 and 4 it works fine - I hover and background changes color with opacity 0.3 and when I move the mouse out, it goes back to white. And when I click it, it changes the background to 0.4 and the hover doesn't affect them anymore. However, this is not working for the first div: the `div` changes background color on hover, but when I click it ,it keeps the hover color, and when I mouse out I see the click color, and every time I hover it changes the hover color again and so on.

Why is it happening only on div 1?

Code:

```
//hover effects
$(".respuesta1,.respuesta2,.respuesta3,.respuesta4").hover(

function () {
    $(this).addClass("respuestahover");
},

function () {
    $(this).removeClass("respuestahover");
});

//on click function for div1        
$(".respuesta1").on("click", function () {
    //if it hasnt been clicked, toogle class and change var to true
    if (prendido1 == false) {
        $(this).toggleClass("respuesta1b");
        prendido1 = true;

        //if any of the other divs are clicked by the time you are clicking unclicked 1, turn them off
        if (prendido2 == true) {
            $(".respuesta2").toggleClass("respuesta2b");
            prendido2 = false;
        }
        if (prendido3 == true) {
            $(".respuesta3").toggleClass("respuesta3b");
            prendido3 = false;
        }
        if (prendido4 == true) {
            $(".respuesta4").toggleClass("respuesta4b");
            prendido4 = false;
        }
        //if is already clicked, turn off and change var to false
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass("respuesta1b");
        prendido1 = false;
    }
});
```

The last part is repeated for every div "respuesta2", "respuesta3", etc..

Any idea?

****EDIT****

I was trying to clean up the code to make a jsFiddle and I think I got it to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/bqySN/2/

I'll just leave the code there if anyone is interested, be aware the code is unpolished and it need more generalisations.

***EDIT 2***

After some testing I actually found the problem:

if I alter the order of my css clases the app goes crazy:

This one is correct, with hover first

```
.respuestahover{
    background-color:#f00;
    opacity:0.2;
}

.respuestab{
    background-color:#f00;
    opacity:0.5; 
}
```

This one is incorrect, hover second:

```
.respuestab{
    background-color:#f00;
    opacity:0.5;
}

.respuestahover{
    background-color:#f00;
    opacity:0.2;
}
```

I'm not really sure why it is behaving like that, but I'm glad I figure it out.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for that.. it could help solving your problem easily...thanks

Comment: Your indentation makes your code hard to read. Can you please format it so it's easier on the eyes?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a class on hover... why would you do that via javascript if you can just use the :hover state from css? For example:

```
#foo .element p { color: red; }
#foo .element:hover p { color: blue; }
```

EDIT:

Sorry, I miss the original question.
If you want to remove the hover effect after clicking, you have lot of different ways to do this. You can remove the class defined with the hover via css, or if you want a jQuery solution you can use mouseenter/mouseleave with .on and then unbind with off.

[See the following fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bqySN/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do you enable hover again after a second click? Nevertheless my code is working for div 2, 3 and 4 but acting weird on the first one. I'll try to modify your example.

Comment: Check out my edits on first post! I figured out the problem, thanks a lot for your help! http://jsfiddle.net/bqySN/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should simplify the bindings to just target them a little more generically, then remove the hover classes on all of them:

```
$(".respuesta").on("click", function (index) {
  $(this).removeClass("hover");
  // do other things
});
```

You can also use the index to find which number they are if they're in a list.

if you want the hover to not override the click, give the click an active class and tell the hovers to work on everything but them:

```
$('.respuesta:not(.active)').hover(function() {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Yea I'm aware I can optimize the code in a more generic form, but since I'm not a code expert I usually work this way untill it works then I do a generic version. I tried removeClass() and is in fact working, when I click after hovering, it removes the hover class and adds the click one, however when I hover the div again, the hover class overrides the click one.

Comment: I updated the code to show how to use the :not selector - which will do what you asked by not putting hovers on ones with active.